# General solutions for trigonometry equations

Tags: trigonometry

I'm taught that how to find the general solution for example $\cos 5\theta=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

But the exercise given by the book is much more complex than the example.

For example, $\sin^2 3\theta+\cos 3\theta+1=0$, $\tan \theta=2\csc2\theta$

I've no idea where to start. Can anyone provide me some resource or guide me for this topic? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, use the Pythagorean identity: $\sin^2 x+ \cos^2 x = 1$ on the sine term, and for the second, re-write it as $\sin \theta \cdot \sin 2\theta = 2 \cos \theta$ and use the double angle formula for sine.

A possible flowchart for these problems might be the following:

1. Express in terms of sines and cosines
2. Factorise where possible.

Then to solve each "factor",

3. Use the appropriate formulae in order for all the trigonometric arguments to be the same (usually double or half)
4. Apply the Pythagorean identity to bring everything into sines (or cosines).

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve the given questions, it might be helpful to use certain trigonometric identities. For example if I am going to solve:

$tan\theta=2csc2\theta$, I will first note that $csc2\theta=\frac{1}{sin2\theta}=\frac{1}{2sin\theta cos\theta}$.

In effect we have:

$tan\theta=\frac{1}{sin\theta cos\theta}$ which means

$sin^2\theta=1$, by invoking the identity $tan\theta=\frac{sin\theta}{cos\theta}$ and multiplying.

I leave the last step for you to solve or answer.

Again the idea is that you can use identities in simplifying the given equations.